# In each row of a numpy array, I have an int, and a python list of ints. How do I convert this list into a numpy int array, without using pandas?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array, where each row contains a list of a int, and a python list of ints. How do I convert the lists into numpy arrays? I am working with very large arrays, and I would like to avoid using Pandas as loading it into pandas will take more memory.

Sample variable:

```
new = np.array([[0, list([4928722, 3922609, 14413953, 10103423, 8948498])],
       [1,
        list([12557217, 5572869, 13415223, 2532000, 14609022, 9830632, 9800679, 7504595, 10752682])],
       [2,
        list([10458710, 7176517,10203584, 12816205, 7484678, 7985600, 2745090, 14842579, 788308, 5984365])],
       [62711, list([6159359, 5003282, 11818909, 11760670])],
       [62712,
        list([4363069, 8566447, 9547966, 14554871, 2108131, 12207856, 14840255, 13087558])],
       [62713,
        list([11252023, 8710787, 4233645, 11415316, 13888594,  10860521, 1798095, 4389487, 4461271, 10070622, 12675925, 729773])]])
```

Sample result I am looking for (some numbers may have been rearranged; I am just giving an example of how it should be structures):

```
new2 = np.array([[0, np.array([ 4928722,  3922609, 14413953, 10103423,  8948498])],
       [1,
        np.array([12557217,  5572869, 13415223,  2532000, 14609022,  9830632,
        9800679,  7504595, 10752682])],
       [2,
        np.array([10458710,  7176517, 10268240,  4173086,  8617671,  4674075,
       12580461,  2434641,  3694004,  9734870,  1314108,  8879955,
        6597761,  7034485,  3008940,  9816877,  1748801, 10159466,
        2745090, 14842579,   788308,  5984365])],
       [62711, np.array([ 6159359,  5003282, 11818909, 11760670])],
       [62712,
        np.array([ 4363069,  8566447,  9547966, 14554871,  2108131, 12207856,
       14840255, 13087558])],
       [62713,
        np.array([11252023,  8710787,  4233645, 11415316, 13888594,  7410770,
       13672430,  6677251, 10431890,  3447966, 12675925,   729773])]] )
```

What I tried:

I tried trying to display only the list, in hopes that I can do some

```
new[:][1] =  new[:][1].tolist()
```

But new[:][1] doesn't display only the lists, and I couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and convert each `list` to an `np.array`:

```
result = np.array([[row[0], np.array(row[1])] for row in new])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[0 array([ 4928722,  3922609, 14413953, 10103423,  8948498])]
 [1 array([12557217,  5572869, 13415223,  2532000, 14609022,  9830632, 9800679,  7504595, 10752682])]
 [2 array([10458710,  7176517, 10203584, 12816205,  7484678,  7985600, 2745090, 14842579,   788308,  5984365])]
 [62711 array([ 6159359,  5003282, 11818909, 11760670])]
 [62712 array([ 4363069,  8566447,  9547966, 14554871,  2108131, 12207856, 14840255, 13087558])]
 [62713 array([11252023,  8710787,  4233645, 11415316, 13888594, 10860521, 1798095,  4389487,  4461271, 10070622, 12675925,   729773])]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert each row into a numpy array as well? I tried `result2 = np.array( [np.array(row) for row in result ])` but it didn't change anything

Comment: nevermind, it looks like each row is already a numpy array. I was confused because they look like lists since they don't have 'np(' but if you index to at each row, it's a numpy array

Comment: Looks like you have a (n,2) shaped object dtype array.  `result[:,0]` are the numbers, 0, 1, ....  `result[:,1]` are the lists (in the original) and arrays in the result.  Check `type(result[0,1])`.

Comment: @hpaulj `type(result[0,1])` is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.